# Firestore data() method does not exist on JSON parsed document after JSON stringified

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am building a FlashCard website using NextJs and firebase. I have a homepage which I want to render server side and so I am using `getServerSideProps`. Inside`getServerSideProps` function, I am fetching all the documents of the current user from firestore and is stored in an array and is returned as `props` as below:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  let notes: DocumentData[];

  // fetch documents here and populate notes array like so [doc,doc,doc,..]

  // data() method works here and returns document fields
  console.log(notes[0].data());

  // NextJs throws error "`object` ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.", so I have to JSON.stringify() the notes
  return {
    props: {
      notes: JSON.stringify(notes),
    }
  }
}
```

Below, I have my homepage where I parse the JSON string and have access to the notes, but now the `data()` method on the document does not exist/works and throws method does not exist errors. If I have to access the document fields, I have to use the `dot operator` on every property of the document till I reach the `fields` property which is nested deep down in the object as follows:

```js
export default function Home({ notes }) {
  
  let docs = JSON.parse(notes); // can access notes
  
  // data() method throws function does not exist error
  console.log(docs[0].data());
  
  // I am only able to access document fields as below
  console.log(docs[0]._document.data.value.mapValue.fields);
  
  return (
      <Layout>
          <HomeContent notes={docs}/>
      </Layout>
  );
}
```

I have searched everywhere and found nothing that helped me why `data()` method won't work. If I directly fetch the documents inside the page component on client side, the `data()` method on the document returns its' fields. I don't know how using JSON serializations affect it. I would always prefer to use `data()` method to access fields than to go that deep plus I am planning to fetch data on server on other pages as well.

I would really appreciate if you can shed some light on it. It took all of my days time.

EDIT: The code that gets notes from firestore:

```js
// inside getServerSideProps
let notes: DocumentData[] = null;

const getNotes = async(ref: DocumentReference < DocumentData > , uid: string) => {
  let tempNotes = [];
  const categoriesSnapshot = await getDoc < DocumentData > (ref);
  const categoriesObject = categoriesSnapshot.data();

  // return if user doesn't have any documents
  if (!categoriesObject) {
    return;
  }

  const promises: [] = categoriesObject.categories.map((category: string) => {
    const userCategoriesRef = collection(database, 'CategoryCollection', uid, category);
    return getDocs(userCategoriesRef); // returns a promise
  });

  const allQuerySnapshots = await Promise.all < DocumentData > (promises);
  allQuerySnapshots.forEach((querySnapshot) => {

    tempNotes.push(...querySnapshot.docs);
  });

  notes = tempNotes;
}

const categoryDocRef = doc(database, "CategoryCollection", uid);
await getNotes(categoryDocRef, uid);
```

Comment: `data()` is a method on DocumentReference objects.  If you call JSON.parse, you do not get a DoumentReference object back.  It is just a plain JS object and will not have a data method.  It's not clear to me why you need to stringify anything at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the clarification. As for the need to stringify, if I pass the array of documents as it is as props, NextJs throws the error `object ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types."`.  Do you think there is any other way to pass the notes unchanged by the look of the error? Would love some insights. Looks like the issue is also a part of NextJs framework.

Comment: Can you provide how you get the "notes"? how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya I have added the code that gets docs from firestore at the end of my question. I am able to get the docs without any problem. Looks like the issue also has to do with the restrictions nextjs has about the data you pass from `getServerSideProps` to the page component.